# How can I organize my files in a project with AWS SAM (Microservices, nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-sam

I need to have an API with the follow stack: AWS SAM & node.js with 2 microservices:

- `users`
- `books`

What I did:

1. `sam init`
2. AWS Quick Start Templates
3. nodejs12.x
4. Name the project as `books`

Now I have the following template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  books

  Sample SAM Template for books
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

My three files looks like this:

```
app
 ┗ books
 ┃ ┣ events
 ┃ ┃ ┗ event.json
 ┃ ┣ hello-world
 ┃ ┃ ┣ tests
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ unit
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ test-handler.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ .npmignore
 ┃ ┃ ┣ app.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┃ ┣ .gitignore
 ┃ ┣ README.md
 ┃ ┗ template.yaml
```

I am new in this kind of serveless thing, I have expirience with express.js & microservices, so my questions...

**How can I organize my files to have microservices?
**Do I have to make severals templates like this**?**

```
app
 ┗ books
 ┃ ┣ events
 ┃ ┃ ┗ event.json
 ┃ ┣ hello-world
 ┃ ┃ ┣ tests
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ unit
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ test-handler.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ .npmignore
 ┃ ┃ ┣ app.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┃ ┣ .gitignore
 ┃ ┣ README.md
 ┃ ┗ template.yaml
 ┗ users
 ┃ ┣ events
 ┃ ┃ ┗ event.json
 ┃ ┣ hello-world
 ┃ ┃ ┣ tests
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ unit
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ test-handler.js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ .npmignore
 ┃ ┃ ┣ app.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┃ ┣ .gitignore
 ┃ ┣ README.md
 ┃ ┗ template.yaml
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide. I will be grateful. I understand the theory, but I can't find any help in how to order my files.

Comment: `How can I organize my files to have microservices?` However you prefer.  `Do I have to make severals templates like this?` No. Unless you want to.   This question needs more clarity as I feel it will just foster/promote opinions without an actual usecase or objective.

Comment: I thought there was a standard for doing microservices but I discovered that in fact it does not exist. And for the templates... in fact I had to do it with several templates, so that when uploading the project to amazon it would not take so long to build. The microservices were made in various repositories. 
Thank you anyway!